# If $a$,$b$,$c$ are distinct real numbers , prove that $(\frac{a}{b-c})^2 + (\frac{b}{c-a})^2 + (\frac{c}{a-b})^2 \ge 2 $ .

Tags: inequality, contest-math

> If $a$,$b$,$c$ are distinct real numbers , prove that $(\frac{a}{b-c})^2 + (\frac{b}{c-a})^2 + (\frac{c}{a-b})^2 \ge 2$ .

**My Attempt :**

Considering the inequality:
$(\frac{a}{b-c})^2 + (\frac{b}{c-a})^2 + (\frac{c}{a-b})^2 \ge 2$

We've : $a^2(c-a)^2(a-b)^2 + b^2(b-c)^2(a-b)^2 + c^2(b-c)^2(c-a)^2 \ge 2((a-b)(b-c)(c-a))^2$

Now substituting, $a-b$,$b-c$ and $c-a$ as $x$,$y$ and $z$ .
Then the inequality becomes
$a^2(xz)^2 + b^2(yx)^2 + c^2(yz)^2 \ge 2xyz$

And by A.M. - G.M. , $a^2(xz)^2 + b^2(yx)^2 + c^2(yz)^2 \ge 3(abc)^{2/3}(xyz)^{4)3}$

But i m in doubt what if any of $a$,$b$,$c$ is zero since it's not mentioned that $a$,$b$,$c$ are non zero reals?

Comment: What have You tried? Please show Your efforts an have a look [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question)

Comment: @PeterMelech yeah sorry sir I was completing that part , so what should be next ?

Comment: Well, looking at the original equation, *one* of $a,b,c$ could be zero, but two or three of them cannot be zero at the same time...

Comment: $\displaystyle \frac{a}{b-c}=x,\frac{b}{c-a}=y$ and $\displaystyle \frac{c}{a-b}=z$

Comment: $a-bx+cx=0,ay+b-cy=0,az-bz+c=0$

Answer (score 3):

Because $$\sum_{cyc}\frac{a^2}{(b-c)^2}-2=\frac{\left(\sum\limits_{cyc}(a^3-a^2b-a^2c+abc)\right)^2}{\prod\limits_{cyc}(a-b)^2}\geq0.$$

Answer (score 1):

Let the minimum of them be $a$. Then, let $b=a+x$ and $c=a+y$ where $x\ne y$ $$\left(\frac{a}{b-c}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{b}{c-a}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{c}{a-b}\right)^2$$
$$=\left(\frac{a}{x-y}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{a+x}{y}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{a+y}{x}\right)^2$$
$$=\frac{a^2}{x^2}+\left(\frac{a}{x-y}\right)^2+\frac{a^2}{y^2}+\frac{2ay}{x^2}+\frac{2ax}{y^2}+\frac{x^2}{y^2}+\frac{y^2}{x^2}$$
I hope you can continue from here.